# logstash 6.3.0 Unknown setting 'mode' for file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am trying to configure `logstash 6.3.0` to read from my gzipped log files and I am not able to get the `mode => "read"` working as described in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-mode).

The logs indicate that the `mode` setting is not supported.  Any suggestions appreciated. Thank you.

My logstash config:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/tmp/logs/application.log.*.gz"
        type => "application"
        mode => "read"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^(?<time>%{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) (\e\[[\d;]+m)?\[(?<logLevel>[A-Z]+)\]"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
            multiline_tag => "multi_tagged"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Log message:

```
[ERROR][logstash.inputs.file     ] Unknown setting 'mode' for file
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade to a newer version.
mode is indeed not a part of `Logstash` config in 6.3, only from the 6.4 version, for references the [6.4](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.4/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-mode) api and [6.3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.3/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-mode)